# Using CEFSharp to set the value of a dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, cefsharp

I am trying to automate filling out a webpage with a dynamic dropdown list.

When a user manually changes the value of that dropdown list, there is a second drowndown list elsewhere on the page the updates.

I am able to set the value of the first dropdown list with my application like so:

```
browser.GetBrowser().GetFrame("mainFrame").ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('ddlist1').value=" + '\'' + 1 + '\'');
```

However, this does not update the second dropdown list, like it is supposed to. Can anyone help?




I am however, able to do this with the standard WebBrowser Control, like so (this is in VB) using .RaiseEvent("onchange"):

```
For f = 0 To frames.Count - 1
    Dim frameDoc As HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames(f).Document
    Dim frameEle As HtmlElement = frameDoc.GetElementById("ddlist1")
    If frameEle IsNot Nothing Then
        frameEle.SetAttribute("value", 1)
        GetOriginalStates()
        frameEle.RaiseEvent("onchange")
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Open Devtools and run your script there https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging its unlikely what you are seeing is CefSharp specific. The dropdown list probably has an event handler to monitor user input and update. Only a speculation as there's no example provided. You should add some additional tags so people familiar JavaScript and html can help you. They'll require a detailed example.

Comment: @amaitland Hey - you're right. This isn't CefSharp specific. I'll update my original posting with more information.

Comment: You can programatically trigger the change event in JavaScript see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @amaitland Got it! Can you just quickly jot down an answer so that I can mark it?